# Php throw is not working from inside catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

When I call $this->get() and it throws an Exception inside of the get method that is not a ClientException the last catch block IS CALLED, however the entire method returns a NULL.

I have confirmed with a var_dump($e) inside of the last catch block that the error is being caught by that catch block...but the throw does not appear to be working!

It's blowing my mind and I don't understand why.

```
public function get(string $url, $params = null): array
{
    $client = new Client();
    try {
        $response = $client->get($url, ['query' => $params]);
        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        if (!empty($response = self::handleGuzzleErrors($e, $url))) {
            return $response;
        }
        throw $e;
    } catch (\Exception | \Throwable $e) {
        var_dump($e);
        throw $e;
    }
}
public function getSub(string $url, array $subs, $params = null): array
{
    $url = strtr($url, $subs);
    $result = $this->get($url, $params);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`throw` != `return`

Try wrapping your call to `$this->get()` in a try/catch like so:

```
public function getSub(string $url, array $subs, $params = null): array
{
    $url = strtr($url, $subs);
    try {
        $result = $this->get($url, $params);
    } catch (\Exception | \Throwable $e) {
        echo "This gets called";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

It doesn't make sense for anything but `null` to be returned if the connection failed and an error was thrown.

If you want a "default" return value when an error is thrown, use `return` instead of `throw`